# Application Defined or Object Defined Error in VBA Macros Microsoft Excel for LastRow calculation

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

new to VBA so this might be a quick fix but I'm having issues with this code. It's at the very beginning of a sub:

```
Sub NewDiscounts()
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim wsOrg As Worksheet, orgnameB As Range, orgListB As Range
    Set wsOrg = Worksheets("Org List")
    iLastRow = wsOrg.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(x1Up).row
    Set orgListB = wsOrg.Range("B3:B" & iLastRow)
```

The fourth line: `iLastRow = wsOrg.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(x1Up).row` is causing an "Application Defined or Object Defined" error and I'm not sure why, as all the syntax seems to be correct. Do you know why this might be the case? How do I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: `xlUp` ... the letter `l` as in `lambda`, not the number `1`. `xl` ---> Excel.

Comment: Also add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. It would flag the undeclared variable `x1Up`.